# GPOs do not apply when logging into Windows 7 via RDP

Tags: windows, group-policy

I am developing a set of GPOs which that I've applied to an OU containing some Windows 7 x64 computers. loopback processing is enabled of course. This computers are located in a different room so i would like to test and further develop them by logging in via rdp.

however when logging in via rdp the gpo's are not getting applied - only when logging in directly at the console. How comes?

Comment: Are you logging in with the same account remotely that you are interactively (at the console) ?

Answer (score 0):

hm interesting. sorted that one out. When using "mstsc /v:win7 /admin" the gpo's are getting applied. '/admin' is the former '/console' switch...

Comment: I've never seen anything remotely approaching this behavior on any version of Windows. I strongly suspect you had some other root cause.